# I cant deploy openproject to heroku

Tags: angular, ruby, heroku, openproject

I cant deploy openproject to heroku following https://www.imeos.com/blog/2015/03/18/deploy-openproject-to-heroku-the-easy-way/ .

Reserch "Failed to compile angular frontend: 127" but there was no solution on the WEB.....
this is log...

```
remote:            ========================================================================
remote:                            Thank you for installing RubyTree.
remote:        
remote:            Note:: As of 1.0.0, RubyTree can only support MRI Ruby >= 2.2.x
remote:        
remote:            Details of the API changes are documented in the API-CHANGES file.
remote:            ========================================================================
remote:        Bundle completed (281.85s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v10.15.3-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Linking frontend plugins
remote:        npm run build
remote:        W, [2020-05-10T15:48:28.635001 #3189]  WARN -- : hook registered
remote:        Cleaning linked target directory /tmp/build_582aed761269158643ec81d4c7f91bbc/frontend/src/app/modules/plugins/linked
remote:        Linking frontend of OpenProject plugin openproject-avatars to /tmp/build_582aed761269158643ec81d4c7f91bbc/frontend/src/app/modules/plugins/linked/openproject-avatars.

remote:        Linking frontend of OpenProject plugin openproject-costs to /tmp/build_582aed761269158643ec81d4c7f91bbc/frontend/src/app/modules/plugins/linked/openproject-costs.

remote:        Linking frontend of OpenProject plugin openproject-documents to /tmp/build_582aed761269158643ec81d4c7f91bbc/frontend/src/app/modules/plugins/linked/openproject-documents.

remote:        Regenerating frontend plugin registry /tmp/build_582aed761269158643ec81d4c7f91bbc/frontend/src/app/modules/plugins/linked-plugins.module.ts.
remote:        Building angular frontend
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Failed to compile angular frontend: 127
remote:        /tmp/build_582aed761269158643ec81d4c7f91bbc/lib/tasks/assets.rake:66:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_582aed761269158643ec81d4c7f91bbc/lib/tasks/assets.rake:65:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_582aed761269158643ec81d4c7f91bbc/lib/tasks/assets.rake:64:in `chdir'
remote:        /tmp/build_582aed761269158643ec81d4c7f91bbc/lib/tasks/assets.rake:64:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_582aed761269158643ec81d4c7f91bbc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile => assets:compile_environment => assets:prepare_op => assets:angular
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Please teach me how to slove. Thank you

Comment: What is the output of `ng build --prod` when you run that command locally?  If you can't build it for production locally, Heroku probably can't either.  Try to build it first - see if there are any errors.

Comment: were you able to solve it? `ng build` works for me.

Comment: hey, i am also unable to deploy openproject on Heruko, if you have a solution please share it.